# Measuring distance with ~300 m range and at least ~2 m accuracy as cheaply as possible

Tags: signal, measurement, tracking

[Very new to Electrical Engineering.]

So what I am trying to come up with is the following:

I want to have a device (receiver) that receives signals and put it in one place, not moving.
Other devices (senders) will be on moving objects that move in open space (with frequent occlusions though) and these senders will send signals to the receiver which, based on these signals, will calculate the distance between the the sender and the receiver. The receiver must be able to differentiate between different senders, like each sender would have a unique signal footprint.
Receiver either saves the data or send it to another device, like pc or smth.

There are some constraints:

1. Senders must be durable (withstand collision in case the tracked object, which is heavy, falls, for example), and small (1 euro coin?)
2. The price should be as cheap as possible, preferably within €100 - €150 (~$110 - $165) for the receiver and 30 senders. Price is the key here, so it's possible to sacrifice up to 100 m of range and up to 1 m of accuracy (so min 200 m range and 3 m accuracy).

But also if you're aware of any devices that is a bit out of this range but does the job very well, please mention them in your answer as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using GPS as a solution here?  Each of your "senders" could simply transmit their GPS coordinates to the receiver.

Comment: Have a look at how aircraft radar transponders work for air traffic control.

Comment: Just curious, what exactly is the application here? What are you tracking? Sure sounds pretty interesting.

Comment: Is this a single installation or is it a solution that will be widely adopted once you figure it out? This matters because you are trying to optimize cost. Sometimes you can spend big R and D money up front to lower unit cost in mass production. So do you have R and D budget or you want something as close to off-the-shelf as possible?

Comment: mkeith It should be mass production, and by mass I mean several thousands of complete sets (1 receiver + ~20-30 senders). As for another question, ideally it would be something off-the-shelf for the prototyping purposes, but then for our specific needs we may design the cases for senders and tweak some other things and outsource the production. We are a group of students so we don't have much money to spend on R&D, maybe we will invite some curious electrical engineering students aboard to help us, but only if we find out that everything works. So it doesn't need to be a state-of-the-art thing

Comment: crossroad Let me leave it a mystery :)

Comment: You should add information about place, there that game happens,  indoor or outdoor, obstacles for RF signal.

Comment: user263983 as I said, everything happens in an open space, that is outdoor and without obstacles. The only obstacle there may be is that objects (30-50cm thick) can occlude each other for short periods of time.

Comment: GPS trackers is the option.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate Ultra-Wideband (UWB) radio technology. They measure the distance between a transmitter and receiver by actually timing the round-trip delay of the radio signal. The company Decawave, just acquired by Qorvo, is one leading vendor of the chips, and costs are <$10.

Experimenters have placed the module on a PCB in the Adafruit Feather form factor, 2" x 0.9". You'll need a rechargeable lithium cell, so it might end up about 0.5" thick. And the antenna needs careful design. But it would be a good challenge for an experimenter.

Comment: Does it gives distance 300 meters?

Comment: @user263983 Range typically quoted as 80-200 meters, but depending on the use case (sports field?) could be greater with somewhat directional antennas, higher power, etc. Range is in the ballpark anyway.